# understanding fractals and especially mandelbrot set

Tags: fractals, mandelbrot

I'm really scratching my head here in an effort to understand a quote i read somewhere that says "the more we zoom inside the fractal, the more iteration we will most likely need to perform".

so far, i haven't been able to find any mathematical / academical paper that proves that saying.
i've also managed to find a small code that calculates the mandelbrot set, taken from here :
http://warp.povusers.org/Mandelbrot/
but yet, wasn't able to understand how zooming affects iterations.

```
double MinRe = -2.0;
double MaxRe = 1.0;
double MinIm = -1.2;
double MaxIm = MinIm+(MaxRe-MinRe)*ImageHeight/ImageWidth;
double Re_factor = (MaxRe-MinRe)/(ImageWidth-1);
double Im_factor = (MaxIm-MinIm)/(ImageHeight-1);
unsigned MaxIterations = 30;

for(unsigned y=0; y<ImageHeight; ++y)
{
    double c_im = MaxIm - y*Im_factor;
    for(unsigned x=0; x<ImageWidth; ++x)
    {
        double c_re = MinRe + x*Re_factor;

        double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
        bool isInside = true;
        for(unsigned n=0; n<MaxIterations; ++n)
        {
            double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
            if(Z_re2 + Z_im2 > 4)
            {
                isInside = false;
                break;
            }
            Z_im = 2*Z_re*Z_im + c_im;
            Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;
        }
        if(isInside) { putpixel(x, y); }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've got an interactive Mandelbrot generator written in Postscript [here](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=mandel2.ps). It gives you direct control of the iterations (the value `/maxit`) through the interactive prompt, but also scales the iterations as a side-effect of zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a scientific answer but a one with common sense. In theory, to decide whether a point belongs to the Mandelbrot set or not, you should iterate *infinitely*, and check if the value ever reaches *Infinity*. This is practically useless so we make assumptions:

1. We iterate only 50 times
2. We check that iteration value ever gets larger than 2

When you zoom into a Mandelbrot set, the second assumption remains valid. However **zooming** means **increasing the significant fractional digits of the point coordinates**.

Say you start with `(0.4,-0.2i).`
Iterating over and over this value increases the digits used, but won't lose significant digits. Now when your point coordinate looks such: `(0.00000000045233452235, -0.00000000000943452634626i)` to check if that point is in the set you need much more iteration to see if that iteration would ever reach 2 not to mention that if you use some kind of Float type, you will lose significant digits at some zoom level and you'll have to switch to an arbitrary precision library.

Trying is your best friend :-) Calculate a set with a low iteration and a high iteration and subtract the second image from the first. You will always see change at the edges (where black pixels meet colored pixels), but if your zooming level is high (meaning: the point coordinates have a lot of fractional digits) you will get a different image.

Answer (score 1):

You asked how zooming affects iterations and my typical zoom to iterations ratio is that if you zoom in to a 9th of the size I increase iterations by 1.7. A 9th of the size of course means that both width and height is divided by 3.

Making this more generic I actually use this in my code

```
Complex middle = << calculate from click in image >>
int zoomfactor = 3;
width = width / zoomfactor;
maxiter = (int)(maxiter * Math.Sqrt(zoomfactor));
minimum = new Complex(middle.Real - width, middle.Imaginary - width);
maximum = new Complex(middle.Real + width, middle.Imaginary + width);
```

I find that this relation between zoom and iterations works out pretty well, the details in the fractals still come well on deep zooms without getting too crazy on the iterations too fast.

How fast you want to zoom if your own preference, I like a zoomfactor of 3 but anything goes. The important thing is that you need to keep the relation between the zoomfactor and the increase in interations.